# iOS How to check if valueForKey exist or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have another question about checking the existence of valueForKey.
Here's my code:

```
id _jsonId = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[_json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&_error];
Monday = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
if ([_jsonId valueForKey:@"Mon"]!= Nil) {
    _keyMon = [_jsonId valueForKey:@"Mon"];
    [Monday addObject:@"Monday"];
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if ([_keyMon objectAtIndex:i]!=[NSNull null]) {

            [Monday addObject:[_keyMon objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }

} else {
    [_keyTues addObject:@"No Class For Today"];
    [Monday addObject:[_keyMon objectAtIndex:1]];
}
```

The idea is, if the `_jsonId valueForKey` came back nothing, I can add this NSString`addObject:@"No Class For Today` incase XCode tells me that:
 `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`

like it has been telling me now. Anyone have any solution?
I tried `if ([_jsonId valueForKey:@"Mon"]!= Nil)` didn't work.
I tried `if ([_jsonId valueForKey:@"Mon"]!= nil)` didn't work.
I tried `if ([_jsonId valueForKey:@"Mon"]!= (id)[NSNull null])` didn't work.
I tried `if ([_jsonId valueForKey:@"Mon"]!= [NSNull null)`  didn't work.

I know that `_jsonId valueForKey` is came back as a pointer, but I have no idea how to check if the pointer is null(or nil in Objective-C if I'm correct). Please help me.

**UPDATE:**
I have tried using objectForKey and here is a code(_jsonId objectForKey is nil, that I know to try testing the code)

```
if (_jsonId[@"Sun"]== nil) {
    [_keySun addObject:@"No Class For Today"];
    [Monday addObject:[_keySun objectAtIndex:1]];
            }
else{
   _keySun = [_jsonId objectForKey:@"Sun"];
   [Monday addObject:@"Sunday"];
   for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
       if ([_keySun objectAtIndex:i]!=nil) {

           [Monday addObject:[_keySun objectAtIndex:i]];
       }
}
}
```

Still, XCode telling me that I'm add a nil into NSArray.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
```

This is driving me crazy...

Comment: What's wrong with `objectForKey`?

Comment: @trojanfoe I may encounter an empty objectForKey under certain condition, and I can't add an nil object into a NSArray

Comment: That's got nothing to do with it.  You can test (as you are now) for `nil` before putting an object into a collection class.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes that is exactly what I have been tring to do, I tried to detect if [_jsonId valueForKey] is nil or not, then I can do something about it if it's nil. But I didn't seem to do the right thing.

Comment: Well start by reading @Tommy's answer; he also advocates using `objectForKey:` instead and makes a good point as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out. Let's look at the code:

```
if (_jsonId[@"Sun"]== nil) {
    [_keySun addObject:@"No Class For Today"];
    [Monday addObject:[_keySun objectAtIndex:1]];
}
else {
   _keySun = [_jsonId objectForKey:@"Sun"];
    ...
```

If there is an object for the key "Sun" then you store it into _keySun. If there is no object, then you store nothing into _keySun. _keySun will be nil. You send an addObject message to _keySun - but any message sent to a nil object does nothing. You then call [_keySun objectAtIndex:1]. Again, sending a message to a nil object does nothing, and returns nil, which is why you add nil to the Monday object and get a crash.

If you had set _keySun to an empty NSMutableArray, you would have crashed for another reason: You try to add *one* object. You can read that one object with objectAtIndex:0. But to read objectAtIndex:1 you need *two* objects in the array.

BTW. You will get [NSNull null] from the JSON parser if the JSON document that you are reading contains an explicit null. So if your JSON contains "Sun": null then objectForKey:@"Sun" will give [NSNull null]. If your JSON doesn't contain the key "Sun" at all, objectForKey:@"Sun" will give nil.

Comment: Yes I see that now. Thank you for answering. Come to think about it that really is the problem. Thank you again

Answer (score 2):

`_jsonId` as defined by:

```
id _jsonId = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[_json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:&_error];
```

... will be either an array or a dictionary. Based on your code I think you're assuming that it's always a dictionary. So you probably want to add:

```
if (![_jsonId isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) ...
```

You then want to know what's in a dictionary, if anything. So use `objectForKey:`. Or, better, just `_jsonId[@"Mon"]`. You'll get an object or you'll get `nil`.

`valueForKey:` is a completely different mechanism, key-value coding. It is defined on `NSObject` so inherited by `NSDictionary` as well as just about everything else. It is defined to raise an exception for an unknown key. Since it raises an exception instead of returning a result, your attempts to compare a result are ineffective.

Comment: I see. But how to check if it's empty? using if(_jsonId[@"Mon"] ==nil)?

Comment: Yep, that'll do. `objectForKey:` or `[@"Mon"]` will return an object if there is one, or `nil` otherwise. Unlike `valueForKey:` no exception will be raised. I've updated the answer. (Obiter: it's unfortunate that these two methods have ended up with similar names and that NSDictionary implements `valueForKey:` so that mistakes don't become apparent until you're suddenly dealing with exceptions; confusing the two is one of the more common Objective-C mix-ups, I think)

Comment: I have tried this method and give it a try using a key with no object in the NSDictionary, still the program crashes with XCode telling me  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: @DevArenaCN `[NSNull null]` is not the same as `nil` so stop using that too

Comment: @trojanfoe Okay I have changed that. Thanks for the heads up. But I still can't use if (_jsonId[@"Sun"]== nil) to tell the key is empty or not...When I got an nil key, it still do the part when it's not nil...